# Why is Page_Load() hit twice on long-loading page?

Tags: performance, authentication, proxy, webforms, page-lifecycle

I have a page that depending on the data it is bringing back can take a very long time (minutes) to load, with the majority of this time spent in a method called from Page_Load().  I have noticed that once a certain time threshold is hit, Page_Load() will be hit a second time.  When I started watching the network tabs in Chrome Dev Tools and Firebug I didn't see any second requests go out, but I did notice a few things:

In Firebug it temporarily flashes a status code of 407 for the long running request.

In the Chrome Timing tab it shows Stalled for several minutes, then Proxy Negotation right before Page_Load() is hit the second time.

What is going on here?  I don't really know much about how proxies and authentication work, but it sure seems like there is some re-authentication going on in the middle of page load which is causing the whole page lifecycle to restart.

Answer (score 1):

407 is a proxy authentication challenge status, which means some proxy is requesting authentication.

Depending on the authentication scheme (e.g. Basic, NTLM, Negotiate, Digest etc), there will be subsequent requests made with additional authentication information (Proxy-Authorization header).  Since these are repeat requests you may not notice the re-request. If there are large payloads involved (e.g. large body on POST/PUT) then these need to be sent again as well.

Comment: But since Page_Load() was originally hit, I can assume that the original request was authenticated by this proxy, right?  What would cause the need for re-authentication?